# php : resize image before caching

Tags: php, image, caching, png, jpeg

this script will load an image and then save a local copy for caching

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

            $imgpochette = $_GET['i'];

            $ENABLE_CACHE = true;
            $CACHE_TIME_HOURS = 744;
            $CACHE_FILE_PATH = "pochette_album/$imgpochette.png";

            if($ENABLE_CACHE && file_exists($CACHE_FILE_PATH) && (time() - filemtime($CACHE_FILE_PATH) < ($CACHE_TIME_HOURS * 60 * 60))) {
              echo @file_get_contents($CACHE_FILE_PATH);
            } else {
                    // Load the requested image
                    $imgdisplay = "http://www.pirate-punk.com/pochette.php?i=$imgpochette&display=1";
                    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imgdisplay));
$width = "30";
$height = "30";
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $image.getWidth(), $image.getHeight());
                    // Send the image
                    imagejpeg($image, $CACHE_FILE_PATH);
                    exit();
              @file_put_contents($CACHE_FILE_PATH, $output);
              echo $output;
            }
```

how can i resize the image to 300x300px before saving it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [resize png/jpeg image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263171/resize-png-jpeg-image)

Comment: i updated my code with the function imagecopyresampled but now i get an error saying the image could not be displayed because it contains errors.

Answer (score 0):

u need to use

```
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
```

check this url once [image resize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php).hope it is help full

Comment: i updated my code with the function imagecopyresampled but now i get an error saying the image could not be displayed because it contains errors.

Comment: can u tell me which type of image your uploading

Comment: the images can be various types (gif, jpg, or png)... the script converts them to PNG after caching them... i just need to resize the PNG before saving it to the cache folder (pochette_album/)